# Different stylesheets in order to print

Tags: javascript, css

My issue is:
I have this web page and i use print type in my css stylesheet.
What i need is to have two buttons, which would be:

```
Client Print
Member Print
```

For a specific web page. The only difference between them is that the second one has a field more to be printed.

I need to have this two buttons that take different stylesheets for the webpage..
Could someone help me?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" media="screen, projection,print" />
```

For the first one i need:

for the second one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style1.css" media="screen, projection,print" />
```

Comment: well... add the first stylesheet if current user is a client, the second - if user is a member.

Comment: use http://api.jquery.com/css/  call it on button click to change css

Comment: Don't you have some kind of user authentication so that you know if the current user is a client or a member?

Comment: I can't..is not that i've divided them, they just should click either one or the other.. Pamma, i didn't see how it could be done..i mean to call a secific css..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function print(o) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
    if (o == 'client') {
        head += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" media="screen, projection,print" />';
    }
    if (o == 'member') {
        head += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style1.css" media="screen, projection,print" />';
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = head;
}
```

Comment: Hi, please could you help me with the print form?
I mean what should i press?
The button or however it is..